# Python/Flask application restarting every time I exit

Tags: python, flask, ubuntu-14.04

I am running a simple Flask application on Ubuntu 14 with (I believe) Python 2.7 (having difficulties with 3.x in the virtualenv). Every time I try to close my application with CTRL+C, it launches the app again immediately. If I close it again, it exits, but leaves one process running I can see with `ps -a`.

If I then run the .py file again, it starts up, then if I exit with CTRL+C, it throws `socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use` and exits.

At this point there are two processes visible with `ps -a`. Any subsequent startups immediately throw the socket.error.

I have noticed this error is only present when the line `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` is left in (changing the IP has no effect).

I am unsure why, and looking for any help into the matter.

[Shell](https://hastebin.com/oloselumok.rb)

[Code](https://hastebin.com/qizaneduha.py)

Comment: We've had the same problem, and have tabled our flask project for the time being. I'm excited to learn what is going on with this as well.

Comment: Flask is not a server. I don't know how many times this has to be said. The development server runs in multithreaded mode by default

Comment: @GinoMempin With debug disabled, the server still restarts on exit, but only once, consistently, and with no error message or remaining processes visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
app.run(host=‘0.0.0.0’, debug=True)
```

instead of

```
app.run(debug=True)
app.run(host=‘0.0.0.0’)
```

The latter should start 2 apps *continuously*.
So when you hit ctrl+C the first time, you are actually terminating the first line, but immediately after that the second line executes and another app starts.

Comment: Thank you, makes perfect sense and resolves the issue!